# Dynamic component loader - Cannot read property 'viewContainerRef' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components, elementref

im following all steps of the ad-banner tutorial on Angular.io. But at the end  after all setup, i get an error comming from this component and function:

Ad-banner.component TS

```
loadComponent() {
    this.currentAdIndex = (this.currentAdIndex + 1) % this.ads.length;
    const adItem = this.ads[this.currentAdIndex];

    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(adItem.component);

    const viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef; ---->ERROR comes from this Line
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;
  }
```

I get the log correctly, the hero data comes to the home component where I'll display the ads, but not with the error, so can anyone sort me out?

EDIT
The Main Directive

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ad-host]'
})
export class AdDirective {

  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

}
```

Comment: When you call this function? It should be called in AfterViewInit or later.

Comment: its onInit like in the docs, but i'll try your sugestion

Comment: this.adHost is undefined when loadComponent() is called. Where is loadComponent() called from?

Comment: constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { } have this in code?

Comment: @Aakash Garg Ive edited the post, yes I have it's in the Directive

Comment: @Mellville what's in the error text?

Comment: posted my answer below.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'viewContainerRef' of undefined
    at AdBannerComponent.loadComponent (ad-banner.component.ts:38)`

Comment: Have you declared your directive in the app.module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component HTML should be :-

```
<div class="ad-banner-example">
              <h3>Advertisements</h3>
              <ng-template ad-host></ng-template>
            </div>
```

You component Ts  should have :-

```
@ViewChild(AdDirective, {static: true}) adHost: AdDirective;
```

You AdhostDirective should be in declarations of your module.

and you should be calling this.loadComponent(); in ngoninit.

Comment: every thing is in place, declarations, entrycomponents

Comment: and the directive inside declarations in module?